# Google Map API v3 - Ajax (Javascript + Jquery) GET issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, get

I am trying to make the map load markers - pulled in from an xml file. It currently does this perfectly. However I also want the map to reload new markers based upon the month passed through from a hyperlink.

When the 'global_month' variable is changed via hyperlink the ajax request fires and the 'data_array' should be repopulated with the new data based upon the date passed to the 'if' statement later on. However it reuses the 'data_array' contents, and doesn't fill it with new data.

I have tried resetting the 'global_month' via 'global_month = []' in the 'change_date_range' function, however - the array doesn't seem to be refilled. I have spent 3 hours trying to work out where I am going wrong, but cannot. Can anyone help? Also is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you very much for you time!

/////////////////////////////////////////////

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">  
                <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "driving_test_centers.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: parseXml
                        });
                    }); 
                    var global_month = 6;

                    function refetch()
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "driving_test_centers.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: parseXml
                        });
                    };          



                var data_array = [];
                var empty_holder;
                var empty_month;
                var info_date;
                var address1;
                var address2;
                var town;
                var county;
                var postcode;
                var lat;
                var lon;
                var male_pass_percentage1;
                var male_pass_percentage;
                var female_pass_percentage1;
                var female_pass_percentage;
                var the_new_date;
                var infowindow;
                var xml_contents;

                function parseXml(xml)
                {
                    $(xml).find("test_center").each(function()    // look for all of the test centers
                    {

                        center_name = $(this).attr('name');
                        address1 = $(this).find('address1').text();
                        address2 = $(this).find('address2').text();
                        town = $(this).find('town').text();
                        county = $(this).find('county').text();
                        postcode = $(this).find('postcode').text();
                        lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
                        lon = $(this).find('lon').text();

                        $(this).find("date_info").each(function()
                        {

                            info_date = $(this).attr('date');
                            empty_month = $(this).find('month').text();
                            male_pass_percentage = $(this).find('male');
                            male_pass_percentage = male_pass_percentage.find('pass_percentage').text();
                            female_pass_percentage = $(this).find('female');
                            female_pass_percentage = female_pass_percentage.find('pass_percentage').text();


                            if(empty_month == global_month){
                                data_array.push([lat,lon,center_name,info_date,male_pass_percentage,female_pass_percentage]);
                            }
                        });


                    });

                }


                function change_date_range(the_new_date){
                    global_month = the_new_date;
                    refetch();
                    init();
                };  




                </script>
                <script>


                function init() {


                    var options = {  
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.3781, -3.4360),  
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
                    };
                    var places;
                    places = null;  

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    var places = data_array;
                    var temp_location;


                    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

                        temp_location = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i][0], places[i][1])

                        // Adding the markers
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: temp_location, 
                            map: map,
                            title: places[i][2]
                        });

                        // Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function 
                        // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
                        (function(i, marker) {

                            // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
                            // i and marker as they were during its creation
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                                // Check to see if we already have an InfoWindow  
                                if (!infowindow) {
                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                }

                                // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                                infowindow.setContent(places[i][2] + "<br />" + global_month + "<br />" + places[i][3] + "<br /><br />Male: " + places[i][4] + "%<br />Female: " + places[i][5] + "%");

                                // Tying the InfoWindow to the marker 
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);

                            });

                        })(i, marker);

                        // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng
                        bounds.extend(temp_location);

                    }

                    // Adjusting the map to new bounding box
                    map.fitBounds(bounds)

                };



                </script>
            </head>
            <body onload="init()">

                    <div id="map" style="width:800px;height:600px"></div>

                    <a href="javascript:change_date_range(7)">click</a>
            </body>
            </html>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

XML file (small part of):

```
http://tinypaste.com/198889bb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not clearing out the data_array array...you just continue to add to it. Why don't you add `data_array = [];` to the beginning of the parseXml function

edit: you should also clear the markers that are already placed...a good way to make that easy is that when you add markers, hold them in an array, then you can loop through it, setting the map attribute of each to null:

```
for (x=0;x<markers.length;x++) {markers[x].setMap(null);}
```

Comment: I tried adding the data_array = [], it loads the current month the first time the link is clicked - ignoring the new month passed through. It works the second time though, i think I am having an issue because I am reloading the map each time. Is it possible to store the xml contents in an array - or would that cause issues?

Comment: Thanks Robot you gave me a starting point. I rewrote the whole thing, works much better, and I understand it all very well now. Cheers!

Comment: Great, I was doing the same thing. I think ideally you'd parse through the xml once, divide it up into unique arrays, and then as you change the target month, clear the map, and loop through one of the existing arrays. you shouldn't need to ajax in the same data more tha once (but maybe you'd change that target to be a script that accepts a month parameter and only gives you part of overall dataset...in which case you may want to call it more than once). Glad you got it on track.

Comment: Is there a better way of adding it to an array other than using a loop? I guess that is a pretty good way, I tried adding the raw XML to a variable, and it didn't go so well. I will try adding them to a loop in the first initial pass through the xml file, then make the script reference the array. Cheers for the idea :)